# Can't override "hitTest" method for UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, hittest, custom-paging

I've created a scroll view, width less than the screen width and set **clipsToBounds=YES**. As the UIScrollView doesn't scroll from anywhere outside the range of its frame, I put the UIScrollview inside a UIView and tried to override the ***"(UIView *)hitTest:WithEvent:"*** method. But it always shows warning **pointInside method not found** (or something like that) in the ***if ([self pointInside:point withEvent:event])*** line and it doesn't work. What did I do wrong?  Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, the problem is I didn't create the UIVIew subclass to override the **(UIView *)hitTest:WithEvent:** while the UIScrollView was in a subview of self.view. So, it is important to check which view inherits the scroll view and write overridden method in the parent view class.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the ScrollView's contentSize in order to allow the ScrollView to scroll. It will only scroll it the contentSize.x is bigger than scrollview.size.x and/or contentSize.y bigger than scrollview.size.y.

Comment: @Koga, my ScrollView scrolls just fine. I've no problem with scrolling. I want to control the ScrollView from the outside of the view frame using hitTest method. And my hitTest method doesn't work. Any solution?